# Visual Studio 2012 crashes when browsing with Windows Explorer - (e.g. File, Open, Project or Project, AddReference, Browse )

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I do make it to the explorer, but then it becomes unresponsive.
I get the dialogue: "MS Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working.  Checking for the problem."
Then I get "MS Visual Studio has re-started."
Then it restarts.

I am unable to browse for anything within VS (like a reference .dll that isn't already part of the reference manager).  Windows explorer works fine externally and all browse functions in other solutions work.

I've tried repair, uninstall and reinstall.  Reinstall appears to have maintained my settings established prior to uninstall.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try the menu item Tools - Import and Export Settings - Reset All Settings.

Comment: Also, go Start - Programs - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - Visual Studio Tools - Visual Studio Command Prompt (2012) -- type without quotes "devenv /resetskippkgs" and if that doesn't work, then try "devenv /safemode"

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: Having same problem here with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: the below instructions will reset all your setting in VS such as (TFS servers, recent projects, history, etc). As if you were running VS for the first time for that user.**

You could try running the below command in:-

- Start
- Programs
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Studio Tools
- Developer Command Prompt for VS2012

devenv /ResetUserData